# 'method' object is not subscriptable trying for google api books

Tags: python, django

Trying to get data from google books API but it is showing the error ' 'method' object is not subscriptable'

I know the “TypeError: ‘method’ object is not subscriptable” error is raised when you use square brackets to call a method inside a class. To solve this error, make sure that you only call methods of a class using round brackets after the name of the method you want to call.

```
def books(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DashboardForm(request.POST)
        text = request.POST['text']
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q='+text
        r = requests.get(url)
        answer = r.json
        result = []
        for i in range(10):
            result_dict= {
                'title':answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['title'], # This line is showing error. 
                'subtitle': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['title'].get('subtitle'),
                'description': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['title'].get('description'),
                'count': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['title'].get('pageCount'),
                'categories': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['title'].get('categories'),
                'rating': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['title'].get('pageRating'),
                'thumbnail': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['title'].get('imageLinks'),
                'preview': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['title'].get('previewLink')
            }
            result.append(result_dict)
            context={
                'form':form,
                'results':result,
            }
        return render(request,'dashboard/books.html',context)
    else:
        form = DashboardForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'dashboard/books.html',context)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also include the traceback?

Comment: @AdamMinas Done. It is showing same error for second one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 7, you write:

```py
answer = r.json
```

But r.json is a method which you should call:

```py
answer = r.json()
```

Comment: It is showing another error 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Yes - `r.json()` is like telling Django to get the response, treat it as a JSON string and load it into a dictionary. Functions are not something that can be included in a JSON string. So what you write cannot possibly result in something valid. Print the various keys and values in your dictionary to better understand its structure.